# PHP MYSQL - Sistema de Login - Só aceita valores numéricos

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Olá. estou com um problema... já googlei bastante a respeito mas não achei nada de sucesso.

meu sistema de login está apenas aceitando senhas numéricas.

exemplo: Usuario: fulano, senha: 123 - desse modo consigo fazer meu login perfeitamente.

já neste outro exemplo: Usuario: fulano1, senha: fivefivefive - Me retorna que meus dados são inválidos.

tabela: usuarios;
minha coluna senha no banco de dados esta formatada nesse padrão:

id: int, length 15, auto increment;
 nome: varchar, length 200, not null;
 senha: varchar, length 32, not null;
 email: varchar, length 100, not null;

```
<div class="">
                    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; color: red;">                                    

                        </div>                                
                            <input name="usuario" name="text" placeholder="Seu usuário" autofocus="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <input name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Entrar</button>
                    </form> </div>
```

abaixo o código de login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('conexao.php');

    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {        
        header('Location: index.php');
        $_SESSION['erro_inpt_vazio'] = "Usuário ou senha não informados";
        exit();
    }

    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usuario']);
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

    $query = "select nome from usuarios where nome = '$usuario' && senha = md5($senha)";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($row == 1) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('Location: painel.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código. vlw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque

```
$query = "select nome from usuarios where nome = '$usuario' && senha = md5($senha)";
```

Por

```
$query = "select nome from usuarios where nome = '$usuario' && senha = md5('$senha')";
```

Seu select deve está chegando assim:

```
select nome from usuarios where nome = 'user' && senha = md5(secreto)
```

por isso só aceita número, falta a aspas simples

Comment: Faltava as aspas simples! muito obrigado, uma falta de atenção minha esse problema.